# Can any one tell me what make and model this bike is? Stolen today

Tags: identify-this-bike, commuter

[image]

It's my bike which was stolen today, only image I have of it. Please, need for the police and insurance...

Comment: Do you have the bill of sale or the bike insurance paperwork?

Comment: No nothing but this photo, bought it secondhand a couple of years ago, all I know is that it is probably 7 or 8 years maybe since it was new. Price range then maybe 400 euros. Any ideas? thanks!

Comment: Once you have some cash, consider buying two bikes.  One nice bike as a replacement, and one ugly used $20 beater bike which is specifically for shopping, where you have to leave it locked up somewhere, and spend more on the lock than the bike.  Your old lock was not up to the task.

Comment: Wise words, I live and learn!

Comment: @Criggie Perhaps in exceptional cases, a more expensive bike is less likely to be stolen than a cheaper bike, in particular if it's the expensive bike is highly unusual (I recall an anecdote where "bike thieves" were stumped on moving a certain unusual model of a recumbent bike at all, when it wasn't even locked, just parking with the parking brake; a bike thief putting those up on craigslist cheaply is more likely to attract attention).

Comment: Do you know that it wasn't stolen from a previous owner when you bought it secondhand? If so, how? What do you expect the thief who stole it today to do with it?  Keep your answers in mind when purchasing a replacement.

Comment: @PatrickOMahony Also, consider that the insurer doesn't care exactly what model your lost bike was.  They need to know what a suitable replacement is that is available now, and what they have to pay out.  If you don't work with the claim officer to a good choice, then you might end up with a sub-$100 BSO because "its a bike" and still have to pay the excess and depreciation anyway.  Insurance claims are horrible.

Answer (score 34):

It's a Specialized Sirrus circa 2012-2014. [Here's a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k_nlIjYsU0Y) from 2013 that shows the bike in detail. Without part photos it's hard to tell the exact trim level, I suppose it's either a "Comp" or "Sport".

Notable features are:

- Flat bars on a road bike.
- Rim brakes.
- Aluminium alloy frame.
- Distinct paint scheme, especially on the fork.
- Frame shape, tubes, junctions.

How I found it:

Google Image for "flat bar road bike rim brakes", look for bikes with matching features. "Sirrus" looked similar, so I searched for "Specialized Sirrus alloy rim brakes" next and look for one with same top tube and fork paint job, that's how I found the video. To narrow down the year and trim, I've looked for "Specialized Sirrus alloy 2011" and other years.

Good luck finding the bike, Patrick!

Comment: Genius!! Thanks so much, felt like an idiot not knowing the make of my ex bike.

Comment: I won't find it, lock was cut in broad daylight outside a supermarket.L But my home insurance covers it I hope. Thanks again..

Comment: Yeah, very likely Specialized, but the brakes look different (though it's hard to tell in the fuzzy picture).

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Good find! I had a Sirrus Sport in about 2011 and the bike here looks like a higher spec model from a similar era, so maybe the Comp or higher. Sporty bar ends for example. can't make out the naming in the photo though to be positive

Comment: maybe maybe 2014 sirrus comp http://everysingle.bike/models/2014-specialized-sirrus-comp notice how the downtube lettering gets a big change from 2013 and earlier

Comment: low spoke count/ radial spoked front wheel indicate a higher spec model than basic as well

Comment: @PatrickOMahony remember to include everything in your insurance - the lights alone could add another $100 to the claim if they were fancy.

Comment: @PatrickOMahony following on from Criggie's suggestion, were they clip in pedals? they look like Shimano pedals with SPD one side and flat pedals the other side? They would have been an upgrade too

Comment: @PatrickOMahony I guess at this point you can also email the manufacture for specific details